# Argument switching on loaded module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a on-screen keyboard in python that I can load into a frame or parent window by importing the module

```
import mykeys
```

Then I can call it by

```
mykeys.thekeys(akey, accountI)
```

Now I am writing a script that contains two entry widget fields. Unfortunately, I can only use one entry widget field at a time, because mykeys module will only accept one entry field reference, or argument. I can detect which entry field I am clicked in by using

```
parentW.bind("<FocusIn>", keyFocus)
```

and in a function

```
def keyFocus(event):
    if accountS.focus_get() == accountI:
        print 'Hello'
    elif accountS.focus_get() == accountIK:
        print 'World'
```

when I click into these fields, it will print the appropriate print statement. I was hoping to use this "hack" to reload the module and activate the correct argument for the field I'm trying to type in, like

```
def keyFocus(event):
    if accountS.focus_get() == accountI:
        reload(mykeys)
        mykeys.thekeys(akey, accountI)
    elif accountS.focus_get() == accountIK:
        reload(mykeys)
        mykeys.thekeys(akey, accountIK)
```

Needless to say, it does not work. What would be the best solution for my problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless the the mykeys module is really poorly written there should be no reason to use `reload`. Your function could be neater but it should work the way it is, so I'm assuming the problem is in the mykeys module. Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes the keyboard that we can test.

Comment: in `mykeys.thekeys(akey, accountI)`, what is `akey` and `accountI`? Are they widgets? Functions?

Comment: mykeys seems to be reliable, other than the fact I have it coded to control only one entry field at a time. The `reload` is something I was trying to do to get the module to "refresh", so that I can "restart" the on-screen keyboard with the new entry widget argument, which is `accountIK`.

Comment: @BryanOakley , `akey` is the frame and `accountI` is the entry widget field.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reload anything. Why can't you write `mykeys` to simply work on whatever widget has focus?

Comment: @BryanOakley , could I take `accountS.focus_get()` and assign it to a variable and make that my entry argument?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. There's just not enough detail in your question. Though, the answer is probably "yes". Whether that's the best solution or not, I can't say.